# Java Scripting API -- Property from JavaScript object is always null

Tags: javascript, java, scriptengine

Below is the code I am running in my Java compiler:

```
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

engine.put("person", "{name: 'Bob', favoriteColor: 'red'}");
System.out.println(engine.get("person.name"));
```

I would expect this to evaluate to "Bob", but instead it gives me `null`. If I try printing just the user object, it properly gives me this output:

```
{name: 'Bob', favoriteColor: 'red'}
```

Why is `person.name`evaluating to `null`? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where is "user" defined in that code?

Comment: You've `put` a variable called `person` and then you are trying to fetch values from `user`. Try using `person.name` instead.

Comment: How did this get so many upvotes? yikes

Comment: Sorry! Just an error in copying, I have changed it. It should be 'person.name'

Comment: So many == 1?  But yeah, it looks like it might be a typo/syntax error.

Comment: The documentation for `ScriptEngine.get()` describes the string parameter as a "key", not an "expression".  Is it possible that it's not evaluating the expression you gave it?

Comment: Yes, that may be the case. If I use the JavaScript print function to print the boolean instead of embedding `engine.get` into a Java print statement, it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the `put` method doesn't evaluate the value passed, but assumes it is meant as a literal. For example `script.put("test", 5)` will put the literal integer value `5` into a variable called `test`.

The second thing that's wrong is that `get` also doesn't evaluate its parameter, but assumes it, too, is the literal name of the variable.

However, it is possible to do what you are trying to accomplish. Try this:

```
engine.eval ("var person = {name: 'Bob', favoriteColor: 'red'}");
System.out.println(((Bindings) engine.get("person")).get ("name"));
```